# How to observe the location of a opened Popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, window, location

I wanted to open an popup and get notify if the user closes the Popup or leaves it through an external link.

```
popup = window.open(
  "http://ec.europa.eu/yourvoice/ipm/forms/dispatch?form=tobacco6", 
  '',
  'status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,copyhistory=no'
);
```

To check if the user closed the popup I set an Timeout that checkes if the popup is open.

```
if(popup.closed)
```

How can i check if the location of the popup is still the inital one?

```
popup.location
```

just return about:blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `onbeforeunload` event.

```
popup.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow it doesn't work. Maybe because of the frameset in the popup.